# moving text up towards the banner and removing abstract heading

Tags: abstract

```
\documentclass[final,9p,cambria,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

%% For including figures, graphicx.sty has been loaded in
%% elsarticle.cls. If you prefer to use the old commands
%% please give \usepackage{epsfig}

%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%% The amsthm package provides extended theorem environments
%% \usepackage{amsthm}

%% The lineno packages adds line numbers. Start line numbering with
%% \begin{linenumbers}, end it with \end{linenumbers}. Or switch it on
%% for the whole article with \linenumbers.
%% \usepackage{lineno}

%% You might want to define your own abbreviated commands for common used terms, e.g.:
\newcommand{\kms}{km\,s$^{-1}$}
\newcommand{\msun}{$M_\odot}

\journal{University of Twente}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc, url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip} % Removing indenting in new paragraphs
\urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={160mm,247mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=30mm,
 }
 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % bold text for captions
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable} % fancy tables, check these before you use them
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}


\usepackage{sectsty}
\includeonly{banner}    

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim = 0cm 0cm 0 4cm ]{Academic research skills banner.jpg}
\end{figure}

\begin{frontmatter}


\title{Enhancing railway maintenance game with IT/OT, cybersecurity, and future industry insights.}

%% use optional labels to link authors explicitly to addresses:
%% \author[label1,label2]{}
%% \affiliation[label1]{organization={},
%%             addressline={},
%%             city={},
%%             postcode={},
%%             state={},
%%             country={}}
%%
%% \affiliation[label2]{organization={},
%%             addressline={},
%%             city={},
%%             postcode={},
%%             state={},
%%             country={}}


\author{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont Author}



\begin{abstract}

Abstract

\end{abstract}



\begin{keyword}

Serious games \sep Railway maintenance \sep IT/OT convergence \sep Cyberphysical systems \sep Cybersecurity


\end{keyword}


\end{frontmatter}



\section{Introduction}
```

Hi, I was hoping somebody could help me with two problems I am having the first is removing the abstract heading and making it empty. I have already tried
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}  and
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{empty}
This however resulted in nothing and when using the abstract package the entire document gets scrambled so i would prefer to not use it.

The other is that on the top of the paper an banner has to be inserted this however creates a whole with page with just the banner on top, and i cant find a way to remove the with space.

Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: Hello. Please edit your post to contain a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (Minimal working example), including you document class and all packages you use. Otherwise we can't reproduce what you are seeing and won't be able to help you properly.

Comment: your banner should not be in a `figure` as it should not float

Comment: Hi I have added the Minimal working example with the packages

Comment: I have added the MWE @Cube707.

Comment: As it should not be a figure what should it be, i tried using include but so far it is all the same @DavidCarlisle

Comment: just `\includegraphics`, possibly in a center environment or in `\makebox[\texwidth][c]{\includegraphics...`

Comment: Both options still generate a blank page with the banner on it, both using it inside the frontmatter and outside the frontmatter @DavidCarlisle. Any other possible methodes?

Comment: `\includegraphics` doesn't make a page or any space it is just positioned as if you had a big letter `X`  probably frontmatter is forcing a page break but I can't look now may look later if no one has answered

Comment: code misses a `$` on l.20 c.28

Comment: also MWE is not complete, no `\end{document}` and complains about `banner.jpg`  missing

Comment: I cannot post the banner.jpg as the information is confidential, i just added an \end{document} at the end @Cube707

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am indeed suspecting the frontmatter is the reason that the \includegraphics does not work, but i cant find any souces about how to use frontmatter and what does and does not work with it

Comment: than use a image that you can post! or use one of the imagees deliverd with every LaTeX distro like `example-image-a`, but like this I have to hunt down why you code isn't compiling and fix it. A MWE must be compilable on *any* system or I doesn't help us find you problem.

Comment: anyway, your simply using a bad template... its coded in a way that makes it evvy un-dynamic and will not let you insert stuff easylie

Comment: why are you trying to change the look of the paper anyway??? the only possible reason to use an Elsevier class is to publish in one of their journals and in that case, they get to choose what the front page looks like, not the author.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the response I am trying to chance it to appease others ofcourse, I had no idea the template would be so restricted. Thanks for the help and it seems i will have to disappoint some people.

Comment: @OleZwarts the whole point of publisher classes like this is to remove style choice from the author and enforce the house style, so not having easy customisation is a design aim, not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: You are using a un-flexible template-class that makes it very hard to modify it.

For your first question: The class uses a atypical naming for the command holding the abstracts title. Its not using the usuall `\abstractname` command but defines its own. Placing `\abstracttitle{}` in your preamble will define an empty name and make it disappear.

Secondly, the howle `frontmatter` procedure is coded in a very strange way. The given commands (including `abstract`, etc)  will store their information and **all** of it will be typeset by the `\maketitle` command which is automatically issued *at the end* of `fronmatter`. This command includes a `\clearage` which makes it start at the top of a fresh page. You have very little options do modify the looks of the titlepage besides the ones given in the documentation. Inserting you banner will require fiddeling around with the classes source-code, so it is probably easyer for you to just create the titlepage yourself from scratch.

EDIT: I found a very (very!) hacky workaround, but there is not much else you can do if you want to stick with this template. This example produces what I assume you want. But it is not stabel so other stuff might break:

```latex
\documentclass[final,9p,cambria,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={160mm,247mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=30mm,
}

\journal{University of Twente}
\abstracttitle{}

% hack to build in a banner-image:
\let\orgresetTitleCounters\resetTitleCounters%
\def\resetTitleCounters{\orgresetTitleCounters\gdef\resetTitleCounters{}%
    {\centering\includegraphics{example-image-a}\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frontmatter}
        \title{Enhancing railway maintenance game with IT/OT, cybersecurity, and future industry insights.}
        \author{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont Author}

        \begin{abstract}
        Abstract
        \end{abstract}

        \begin{keyword}
            Serious games \sep
            Railway maintenance \sep
            IT/OT convergence \sep
            Cyberphysical systems \sep
            Cybersecurity
        \end{keyword}
    \end{frontmatter}


    \section{Introduction}
        Lorem ipsum dlor sit atem.

\end{document}
```

[image: rendered result]

Comment: Hi, wow thanks for the answer, i knew latex could be resticted in some ways but always thought with enough google i could solve it. Thanks for the help and the explanation, i wont be using templates any time soon.

Comment: There are much more open templates you could use. As @DavidCarlisle pointed out the restrictiveness is probably by design.